# Spring Boot: Can we have seperate thread pool for each request?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I've implemented asynchronous execution for a method in my application using Spring Boot @Async. I'm having a custom thread pool with 20 thread. In a for loop calling the async method for 30 times.

Each individual request is executing asynchronously but when i made two different requests at the same time to my API from browser, first request is executing and then second. Not both requests executing the same method parallely.

I thought when first request reach the app, it's started executing the async method and since it's being executing for 30 times and my pool is having 20 threads, all threads are busy in executing first request. So even second request came for execution also since the pool of threads busy, the other request is waiting till a thread becomes free in the pool.

Can we have separate thread pool for each individual request. or any way that we can make execution of each request separate independent of other request processing.

Here is my code sample.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class AppBootStrap
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(AppBootStrap.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public AsyncTaskService asyncTaskService() {
    return new AsyncTaskService();
  }

  @Bean(name="customExecutor")
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    poolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    poolExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    poolExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("customPoolExecutor");
    poolExecutor.initialize();
    return poolExecutor;
  }
}

**Controller Class:**

@RestController
public class TaskController
{
  @Autowired
  private TaskService taskService;

 @RequestMapping("/performAction")
 public void performAction() {
    taskService.performAction();
 }
}

**Service class**

@Service
public class TaskService
{
  @Autowired
  private AsyncTaskService asyncTaskService;

  public void performAction()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        asyncTaskService.greetings(i);
    }
  }
}

**Async Method Class**

public class AsyncTaskService
{
  @Async
  public void greetings(Integer i)
  {
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(500 * (i + 10));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Welcome to Async Service: " + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Not both requests executing the same method in parallel.` This is flat out wrong, in a servlet container, each request gets it's own thread, so everything is per definition always in parallell. But if there are no threads left ofc. other requests need to wait, but every request is always executed in parallell.

Comment: and if you want to use your custom executor you should provide the name of it in the async annotation `@Async("customExecutor")`

Comment: Your words are absolutely correct. But here in this scenario, two diff requests reaching the server so definitely the execution will be parallel but when the execution comes to this particular logic (Asynchronous method execution), waiting is happening. And for async annotation i have added custom executor also. Forgot to mention in above code.

Comment: please update your code then with the correct code

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Bean(name = "apiTaskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor apiTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Bean(name = "lruTaskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor lruTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

The Way to do this is to create two Thread different Thread Pools using Different Qualifier names. (As shown above)

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("apiTaskExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor apiTaskExecutor;
```

Then autowire the required pool using the qualifier you have given . You can also use the `@Async` annotation instead of autowiring . I prefer this way.

If I am not wrong this way of having different thread pools for different Tasks is known as bulkhead pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the customExecutor bean is a singleton. This means that when the second request tries to use this bean it finds all the threads of the thred pool busy. You can try to make the customExecutor bean non-singleton by using the @Scope("prototype") annotation  which will cause a new one to be instantiated whenever a bean of this type is requested.

Comment: @Bean(name = "customExecutor")
  @Scope("prototype")
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   poolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
   poolExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
   poolExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("customPoolExecutor");
   poolExecutor.initialize();
   return poolExecutor;
  }